# I keep getting `handleColor` is not a function error

Tags: reactjs

I have some problem with a function I set up to change the background color of a button when it is clicked.
I setup the function in a parent component below:

```js
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import Aside from './Aside';
import Content from './Content';

const Dashboard = () => {
  let asideRef = useRef(null);

  
  const handleColor = color => {
    asideRef.current.style.backgroundColor = color;
  };

  return (
    <div className="d-flex flex-row" id="main_wrapper">
      <Aside handleColor={handleColor} postedRef={asideRef} />
      <Content />
    </div>
  );
};


export default Dashboard;
```

in the child  component it is called  in this manner:

```js
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { createRef } from 'react';




class Aside extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      btn: true,
      btnEn: true,
      background: '#fff',
    };
    
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  

 

  handleClick = () => {
    const { btn } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      btn: !btn,
    });
  };

 

  render() {
    const { btn, btnEn, background } = this.state;
    const { handleColor, postedRef } = this.props;
    console.log(this.props);
   

    return (
      <div className="d-flex flex-column asidebar" id="aside_wrapper" style={{ width: '20%', height: '100vh' }}>
        <div className="d-flex  flex-row justify-content-center nav-header">
          <a href="/dashboard" className="brand-logo">
            <picture>
              <img src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/25479050/99581983-c1c18e00-29e1-11eb-9bd3-4a53585456cb.png" className="img-fluid img-thumbnail" alt="plaschema logo" />
              <source media="(min-width:650px)" srcSet="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/25479050/99581983-c1c18e00-29e1-11eb-9bd3-4a53585456cb.png" type="image/svg+xml" />
              <source media="(min-width:465px)" srcSet="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/25479050/99582047-d736b800-29e1-11eb-92f3-83dce3912e39.png" type="image/svg+xml" />
            </picture>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div className="link_container d-flex flex-column">
          <button type="button" className="buttonTrue" ref={postedRef} onClick={() => { handleColor('#f4f2f6'); }}>
            <Link to="/">
              <i className="lni lni-dashboard" />
              <span className="link_name">Dashboard</span>
            </Link>
          </button>

          <button type="button" className={btnEn ? 'buttonTrue' : 'buttonFalse'}>
            <Link to="/enroll">
              <i className="lni lni-tab" />
              <span className="link_name">Enrollment</span>
            </Link>
          </button>


          <Link className=" icons accreditation-wrapper" to="/accreditation">
            <i className="lni lni-checkbox" />
            <span className="link_name">Accreditation</span>
          </Link>


          <Link className=" icons subscription-wrapper" to="/subscription">
            <i className="lni lni-tab" />
            <span className="link_name">Subscription</span>
          </Link>


          <Link className=" icons service-wrapper" to="/service">
            <i className="lni lni-control-panel" />
            <span className="link_name">Service Usage</span>
          </Link>


          <Link className=" icons report-wrapper" to="/report">
            <i className="lni lni-library" />
            <span className="link_name">Reports</span>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default Aside;
```

After setup, anytime I click on the only button I set it up on as a test, I keep getting this error page `handleColor is not a function`. Right now I can't think of what the issue maybe because I have tried several approaches to get it to work but the error is still there. Below is the code of the component I am trying to apply it on:

[image: error page]

Looking forward to helpful responses. Thanks.
The question has been updated for more insight. Sorry for the earlier issues with the first iteration.

Comment: You are missing 'this', should be this.handleColor..

Comment: why are you using it from `this.props`, it is `this.handleColor`

Comment: it was an omission. I totally forgot that I should remove it. I ought to have removed it.

Comment: That `bind` is unnecessary with arrow methods.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the `handleColor` code after the last edit.

Comment: yes the bind is unnecessary but it's not the issue in focus, that's why I left it like that. However what stumps me all the time is that `handleColor is not a function` when I have passed it appropriately as a prop to the Aside component.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with

```
const handleClick = () => {
```

or

```
function handleClick () {
```

Comment: The component is stateful so both approach did not work.I had to do `handleColor(param){// some code}` and then bind it in the `constructor` and also used `this.handleColor(params)` before it stopped throwing errors. However The desired behavior is not what I have currently. Yes it changes background but it does on double click instead of  one click.

Answer (score 0):

You're wrongly referring the `handleColor`. `handleColor` is not a prop, it is a component method, you can use like `this.handleColor`

```
const { handleColor } = this.props // this is wrong, it's not a prop method
<button type="button" className="buttonTrue" ref={this.colorSwitch} onClick={() => { this.handleColor('#f4f2f6'); // this is right }}>
            <Link to="/">
              <i className="lni lni-dashboard" />
              <span className="link_name">Dashboard</span>
            </Link>
          </button>
```

I have created sample example here with some of your code. Check out [this link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-react-class-fjjmbd)

Comment: `const { handleColor } = this.props ` was an approach I tried earlier and it wasn't working. I was supposed to remove that line but I forgot. Anyways I have removed it but it's still the same error page

Comment: Can you update the code which you've tried after removing `const { handleColor } = this.props` and did you try above approach

Comment: I have created example here. Check it out [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-react-class-fjjmbd)

Comment: The question has been updated. Actually, two components are involved, and it seems that whenever I click on the button the effect I want does not work because there was some form of re-rendering. It will only work when I double click.